# subquery returning more than 1 value, error Msg 512

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2012.

I am not sure how to get my subquery to work. It returns more than 1 value which is not permitted. I want a sum of a quantity per customerID. The `customerID` exists in `tblOrder`, the `QuantityOrdered` in `LineItem` table.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, ProductID, 
    SUM(QuantityOrdered) AS QuantitySum,
    (SELECT (SUM(QuantityOrdered)) 
     FROM LineItem
     INNER JOIN tblOrder ON tblOrder.OrderID = LineItem.OrderID 
     GROUP BY CustomerID) as PRACTICE
FROM 
    tblOrder
INNER JOIN 
    LineItem LI ON tblOrder.OrderID = LI.OrderID
WHERE 
    OrderDate BETWEEN '2016-01-31' AND '2016-03-01'
GROUP BY 
    ProductID, CustomerID
ORDER BY 
    CustomerID
```

Comment: i know the second sum(QuantityOrdered) seems redundant but i am editing that into a computed value once i figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Well your subquery will return a sum for each CustomerID as you're grouping by customer id. So you have multiple rows of subquery for each row of the main query.

Comment: in your sub query you are grouping it by CustomerID, so for each customer you will get a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `GROUP BY CustomerID` in the subquery with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT      CustomerID,
            ProductID,
            sum(QuantityOrdered) as QuantitySum,
            (
                    SELECT      (sum(QuantityOrdered))
                    FROM        LineItem    AS LI_sub
                    INNER JOIN  tblOrder    AS O_sub    ON O_sub.OrderID = LI_sub.OrderID
                    WHERE       O_sub.CustomerId = tblOrder.CustomerId
            ) as PRACTICE
FROM        tblOrder
INNER JOIN  LineItem LI ON tblOrder.OrderID = LI.OrderID
WHERE       OrderDate BETWEEN '2016-01-31' AND '2016-03-01'
GROUP BY    ProductID, CustomerID
ORDER BY    CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want a sum of a quantity per customerID

For all the order or only a the selected ?

Perhaps this what you want to achieve ?

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
       ProductID, 
       SUM(QuantityOrdered) as QuantitySum,
       SUM(SUM(QuantityOrdered)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID) as QuantitySumByCustomerID
FROM  tblOrder
      INNER JOIN LineItem LI ON tblOrder.OrderID = LI.OrderID
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '2016-01-31' AND '2016-03-01'
GROUP BY ProductID, CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID
```